# Erro NodeJS e modulo MSSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, estou com um erro no modulo MSSQL do nodejs para conexões com SQL Server. A conexão ocorre normal, o problema está na hora de realizar as query, a função não me retorna nada no callback.

Código da conexão:

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'ip',
    database: 'database',
    connectionTimeout: '5000',
    requestTimeout: '5000',
    options: {encrypt: true}
};

var pool = function(){
    var conn =  new sql.Connection(config, function(err){
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        //console.dir(request);
        return request;
    });
    return conn;
}

module.exports = function(){
    return pool;
}
```

DAO:

```
function CampanhaDAO(connection){
    this._connection = connection;
    //console.log(this._connection)
}

CampanhaDAO.prototype.getCampanhas = function(){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM notificacao_campanha";

    this._connection.query(sql, function(err, recordset){

        console.log(recordset);
    });
};

module.exports = function(){
    return CampanhaDAO;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mude seu método `getCampanhas` para trabalhar com promessas e adicione o método `connect` antes de executar a `query`:

```
CampanhaDAO.prototype.getCampanhas = function(){
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM notificacao_campanha";
  var conn = this._connection.query(sql);

  new conn.Request().connect(function(err) {
    conn.query(sql).then(function(recordset){
      console.log(recordset);
      conn.close();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  })
};
```

Comment: Já tentei, ele simplesmente trava ao tentar fazer a query e não me retorna nada no callback

Comment: Adicionei um `catch` no meu exemplo, tenta assim

Comment: { name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Connection is closed.',
  code: 'ECONNCLOSED' }
Estranho, ele está fechando a conexão

Comment: @JoãoVictor fiz mais uma alteração, tente assim

Comment: consegui conectar, o problema agora é que ele me retorna o erro: "Could not find stored procedure 'S'"
Ele ta parando na primeira letra e acha que aquilo é uma procedure

Comment: @JoãoVictor fiz mais uma alteração. Verifique se assim funciona

Comment: Deu "object "Promise" has no method 'query'

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou o método recomendado na documentação através de async/await?

```js
const executeQuery = async (query) => {
try {
 const pool = await sql.connect(config);
 const result = await pool.request().query(query);

 return result;
} catch (error) {
 console.error(error);
} finally {
 sql.close();
}
};
```